How to handle Firestore map/array data that is inside of another map in SwiftUI?
I am new to Firestore/Firebase, Swift and SwiftUI so apologies for any simple mistakes I have made in asking the question / during coding
I am making a fitness app and am currently trying to display the user's workout plans. I have been able to perform simple selects, such as the plan's name from firestore, but the exercises are inside an 'exercise' map that contain each exercise as well as its relevant data, with each exercise being its own map:
as so
Not sure if this is correct practise but that's why I'm here
This is my current PlansViewModel code 
The reason this is a map is because I am using these plans for a 'live training' feature, where each plan is walked through. Due to this, I need multiple exercises inside each plan that have their own data (as you can see in the database screenshot) and you can not (to my knowledge) store arrays inside of arrays
The 'Name' and 'User' select statements work as intended but I get confused when maps, arrays and references are brought into the equation on how I'd display them as I am used to SQL
I tried to start simple and display just the ExerciseName from the database:
 return Plans(id: d.documentID,
              Name: d["Name"] as? String ?? "",
              User: (d["User"] as? DocumentReference)?.documentID ?? "",
              ExerciseName: d["ExerciseName"] as? String ?? ""

As I am already displaying each plan that the user has assigned to them through a for loop on the PlansView:
ForEach(model.list, id: \.id) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading,
                       spacing: 16) {
                    Text(item.Name)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .bold()
                    Group{
                        Text("Exercises:")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .bold()
                        Text(item.ExerciseName)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }}

However this displayed no items
I know this is due to the fact I do not refer to a map but I am not sure how to properly write it

What does "However this did not work" mean? No items displayed? They didn't display in the order you expected? Something else? Can you include a [mre]?

Welcome to SO. It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as text, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, links are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at No Images Please

Two things. Array's are inherently hard to work with in NoSQL so best to avoid them - there are often better storage methods. Second, Name, User are not at the same 'level' as ExerciseName - that's deeper into the structure so you need to code for reading Exercise1 and then within that ExerciseName. See the Custom Objects section and then this is a must read Mapping Data
